# How to stop application creating new settings folder within 'Application data'?

Tags: user-profile, application

In Windows 2003, `Document and settings` folder a user is experiencing a problem where the application ('Toad') keeps creating a new settings folder at each logon instead of using only the first one i.e. 9.7.

For example folder below contains folders 9.7, 9.7 (1), 9.7 (2) and 9.7 (3)....

> Documents and Settings\xxxx\Application Data\Quest Software\Toad for Oracle

So how can I force it to use folder 9.7 and stop it creating and using additional ones like 9.7(4), 97.(5) everytime that user logs on?

Comment: Call Quest (owned by Del now) and ask them what the #@%$ is going on with their app?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this error is the Read Only attribute assigned to the existing folder. The current fix to resolve the issue would be to open a command prompt and issue the following command for each individual affected folder:

```
C:\> attrib -R \\folderpath\foldername**
```

Comment: Thanks Zak. Please clarify do I to do attrib -r 'Documents and Settings' (and it is inherited by sub folders) or full path: 'Documents and Settings\xxxx\Application Data\Quest Software\Toad for Oracle\9.7'? Also does Windows automatically make 'Documents and Settings' and its sub folders readonly by default? Thanks

Comment: I believe its recursive down to the subfolders but you might want to check this write up on it: https://www.idp.net/NTFS/